# Trap on DEBUG signal for the dash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, dash-shell

With the bash shell, you can install a trap on the synthetic `DEBUG` signal. This is useful and will execute your function or bit of code on every shell command. For example:

```
$ trap 'logger -t shell "${BASH_COMMAND}"' DEBUG
```

The idea here is to install the trap in a file dropped in, for instance, `/etc/profile.d/bash-logger` and have any user shell session commands logged automatically to syslog whenever they happen. This is also useful to [easily trace remote commands](http://www.streppone.it/cosimo/blog/2013/03/logging-nagios-remote-commands/).

Looking at the dash shell source code, I seem to understand there's no such `DEBUG` signal available.

Are there any workarounds or alternatives to achieve the same result with the dash shell?

Comment: What about `while read -r line; do logger -t shell "$line";   command "$line"; done < myscript.sh` ? If it works I may add some line more in an answer.

Comment: @Hastur I think you mean `eval "$line"`

Comment: @StevenPenny Yes, I was writing `eval <command>` and I cancel the wrong part, it happens... of course always if you  do not want to force your script to use commands on disk instead of the alias/function ones...`◉‿◉`

Comment: Sorry but that's not helping very much. The idea here is to install the trap in a file dropped in, for instance, `/etc/profile.d/bash-logger` and have any user shell session commands logged automatically to syslog.

Comment: This is not really the right site for this question. I wont be adding any more bounties if this one does not work. You should consider deleting this and reposting on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @cosimo: Are you sure you are asking the right question? What exactly are you trying to do? Log all commands run by an interactive user? There may be a simpler way to do what you're trying, such as the `script` command, `lastcomm`, or `auditd`.

Comment: why you are not using self bash debugging feature ,  for debugging refre to     
#!/bin/bash -xv

Answer (score 0):

The most thorough approach would be to re-compile the shell with syslog support enabled. That also gets around shells that (for whatever reason) don't load ~/.*whatever*-profile or ~/.*whatever*-rc.

This is included as an option in the standard source for Bash, but for other shells you might need to find or write a patch.

I would hesitate to recommend reading and `eval`ing line-by-line, because commands can span multiple lines and `eval` of half a command will either fail, or do the wrong thing. Affected command types include: pipelines and conditional commands (where each line ends with `&&`, `||` or `|`), compound commands (including bracketed groups), lines continued with backslashes, multi-line quoted strings, and `<<` here-docs. (There are probably more than I haven't thought of.)

For limited cases you may find `set -v` or `set -x` useful, combined with redirecting stderr into a pipe to logger. However it's imperfect as also redirects stderr from the programs you run. (In Bash you can choose a different filedescriptor for `set -x` to write to, which solves that problem.)

I would point out that if you go
`ssh host some_command`
then there's no interactive or login shell involved, so your rc files don't get loaded, which would bypass your logging.